# PHP form data reinserting input into Wordpress database each time page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having a problem when submitting and passing information from an HTML form into a Wordpress database. I am using `<form method="post">`. The form inputs are successfully inserted into the database; however, when I click refresh on the browser, the same data from the previous submission is re-inserted in the table, and is done so each time the page is refreshed. If I exit the browser, this stops the error; however, I do not want to have to close the browser each time I enter the information.

I am not sure if the problem is in the HTML, or the PHP.

I have also tried using `wp_redirect($url); exit;` (redirecting to the same page), in the hopes that the redirect will clear any code that was stuck in the browser from the first submission. However, that does not fix the problem either.

Is there a way to clear the data so that when I press refresh, nothing further is submitted, until I manually fill out the form, and then re-submit?

I have tried coding `wp_redirect($url); exit;` after  in the HTML portion of my template page. Should I be placing this code somewhere else in the PHP file?

Comment: So if the data is correctly passing to the database, what is the problem here. can you please explain the problem more specifically ?

Comment: I have a form that I am using to collect some data through my Wordpress site. The form is on the front end of the site (the URL is: localhost/wordpress/cost-of-goods-sold). When I fill out the form and click 'submit', the data gets posted within the Wordpress database (phpMyAdmin, in my case). However, without exiting the page, if I click refresh, the same data from the previous submission gets re-inserted into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by placing the `wp_redirect( $url); exit();` code within my theme's functions.php file.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitCOGS'])){
    $data = array (
        'date' => $_POST['date'],
        'source' => $_POST['source'],
        'items_purchased' => $_POST['items_purchased'],
        'receipt_total' => $_POST['receipt_total'],
    );

    $table_name = 'cogs';
    
    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

    $url = "/wordpress/cost-of-goods-sold";

    wp_redirect ( $url );
    exit ();
}
```

Now when I fill out the form, and click submit, the page re-loads itself. If I click refresh, the form does not reinsert the data.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to all the `headers` functions, `wp_redirect` can only be used before any output of the page.

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76991/wp-redirect-not-working-after-submitting-form) for additional information.

Move `wp_redirect` before any output is done, for example where you manage your `POST` data.

Furthermore, as presented in the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) `wp_redirect` doesn't exit automatically. You need to put an `exit();` after it.

```
if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
    exit;
}
```